# C++: Why debugger is showing parameter values unchanged?

Tags: c++, parameters

Using MinGW here to compile this C++ program:

```
int function(int n1, int n2){
    n1=10;
    n2=20;
    return;
}


int main()
{
    int a=89;
    int b=16;
    function(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the debugger showing the parameter values as if no new value had been assigned to them?

[image: debugger]

At the debugging point I would expect `n1` to be 10 and `n2` to be 20. So is this a misconception I have?

Edit: Adding requested info. I used Qt Creator as an IDE (v. 2.7.2) but this is a plain C++ project (no Qt involved). Compiler is MinGW 4.8 32 bits. Debugger is GDB.

Comment: You compiler might have optimized out those assignments.

Comment: If you intend the assignment in the function to affect the values in `main()`, you'll need to pass them by reference, e.g., `void function(int& n1, int& n2)`.

Comment: I understand I should pass by reference if I want the changes to persist, but I thought that within the function scope the parameters would show the new values assigned in the function body. Compiler optimization could be an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of just `return` do `std::cout << n1 + n2;`  If there are optimizations, then this may force the compiler to actually declare and use `n1` and `n2` (but still no strong guarantee the compiler simply did an addition without declaring variables).

Comment: When in doubt, print the assembly language of the function.  The *truth* will be there.

Comment: If you use `g++`, then I would suggest to combine `-g` always with `-O0`. If I understood it right, this is the default but it doesn't prevent you to combine `-g` with a higher optimization level (probably accidentally).

Comment: Please add to your question the _exact_ details of how you compiled/built the program's executable file.

Comment: I could not reproduce this. What is the exact version of MinGW compiler are you using? What optimization flags do you use? What debugger are you using?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I just added some info about compiler, debugger and IDE used.

Comment: What are the compiler options being used? For instance what is the optimizer level, etc.?